# Where and When is Application (TApplication) instance created?

Tags: delphi, debugging, initialization, delphi-5

Where and when is the `Application` instance created? 
(Same goes for the `Screen` instance) .

I don't see anything in the `Forms` or  `System` `initialization` section.
In the CPU windows before `Application.Initialize`, I see a call to `@_InitExe` (SysInit) - which leads to `_StartExe` (System) and a whole lot of `asm` code - Which does not create the `Application` instance as far as I can tell.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's easy enough to work this out from the code. You just do a text search for `TApplication.Create`. For example using the IDE's Find in Files feature.

But you can always be lazy and get the debugger to do it.

1. Enable Debug DCUs.
2. Set a breakpoint in `TApplication.Create`.
3. Run.

When the program breaks, look at the call stack. You will see that the `TApplication` object is instantiated from `InitControls` in the `Controls` unit. And `InitControls` is called from the `initialization` section of the `Controls` unit.

The full call stack for a plain vanilla VCL app looks like this:

```
Vcl.Forms.TApplication.Create(nil)
Vcl.Controls.InitControls
Vcl.Controls.Vcl.Controls
System.InitUnits
System._StartExe(???,???)
SysInit._InitExe($5A81BC)
Project1.Project1
:749933aa kernel32.BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x12
:76f09ef2 ntdll.RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x63
:76f09ec5 ntdll.RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x36
```

Doing the same thing with `TScreen.Create`, you will see that the `TScreen` object is also instantiated in `InitControls()`.

I won't try and explain all of this. I think there's enough information and advice here for you to work it all out from here. Although this is the call stack from an XE3 application, it will look just the same for your Delphi 5 application.

Comment: Makes me wonder why Application is declared in Forms unit in the first place (Controls uses Forms, Forms uses Controls)...

Comment: Controls only uses Forms in implementation. TApplication has to be declared higher up than TForm since it refers to TForm in its interface section.

Answer (score 12):

The Application instance is created in the InitControls procedure of the Vcl.Controls.pas unit.

```
procedure InitControls;
begin
...
  Application := TApplication.Create(nil);
...
```

InitControls is called in the initialization section of the same unit:

```
initialization
  ...
  InitControls;
```